# Array been cleared

Tags: arrays, node.js, api, reactjs, loops

So I have this code that adds data to an array which is runs every second:

```
          var vehiclesT = asset.assetIDs;
          if(!asset.assetIDs){
            vehiclesT = [];
          }
          var y;
          var vehicles = [];
          for(y=0; y< vehiclesT.length; y++){
            var url = 'api/assetName/?vid='+vehiclesT[y]+'&id='+id;
            fetch(url, {credentials: 'include', method: 'get'}).then(function(body){
              return body.text();
            }).then(function(data) {
              vehicles.push(data);
              console.log(vehicles);
            });
          }
          console.log(vehicles);
          vehicles = vehicles.map(function(vehiclef, index){
            return(
              <li key={index}>{vehiclef}</li>
            )
          });
```

So the log in the for loop is printing out an array to the console with the expected values in it. The problem is that once the for loop ends the vehicles array is cleared for some reason so the second console log prints out an empty array, why is this and how can I stop it?

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is not cleared, since javascript is async, your 2nd console.log runs first before your loop executes.

Promise/callback is the best way to solve this issue.

Call back way:

```js
var vehiclesT = asset.assetIDs;
  if(!asset.assetIDs){
    vehiclesT = [];
  }
  var y;
  var vehicles = [];
  for(y=0; y< vehiclesT.length; y++){
    var url = 'api/assetName/?vid='+vehiclesT[y]+'&id='+id;
    fetch(url, {credentials: 'include', method: 'get'}).then(function(body){
      return body.text();
    }).then(function(data) {
      vehicles.push(data);
      console.log(vehicles);
      if(y == vehiclesT.length - 1){
        vehicles = vehicles.map(function(vehiclef, index){
          return(
            <li key={index}>{vehiclef}</li>
          )
        });
      }
    });
  }
```